# client-server programme

Tags: c

We have made simple `client.c` and `server.c` programme in an UNIX environment.  We are using it transfer a simple text file by first opening it, then reading it and sending using `open`, `read`, and `send` system calls; on client side I am receiving it, and writing it by creating a file on server machine.  The transfer is taking place quite smoothly but the file recieved at the client side is not exactly the same on the server side.  In between the readable characters there are some unreadable characters.  Can you please tell me what could be the possible reason for this?  Though the most part of the file is same, only a small part in between has some discrepancies.

Code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/m7a022388).

Thanks!

server side loop:

```
do
{
    n=read(t,buf,100);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
    send(connected, buf,strlen(buf), 0);    
} while(n!=0);
```

on client side

```
do
{
    bytes_recieved=recv(sock,recv_data,100,0);
    count=write(t,recv_data,strlen(recv_data));     
} while(bytes_recieved!=0);
```

Comment: please show your code (or relevant snippets, in particular the read and write loops)

Comment: where should i paste the code .should i paste it here only by editing the question.Sorry for this question ,but i am relatively to this forum and many people get irritated if we some thing long or something they probably dont like.
Thanks

Comment: If it's a lot of code, you can use some kind of paste board and just add the link. If it's a small amount of code, you can put it directly in the question. Either way, you should edit this question and add the new information.

Comment: There could be any number of problems, but we need to see more code than you posted.

It could be that buf is too small to read the 100 bytes of the file you've read in, or that recv_data is too small to read 100 bytes from the socket. There are, in fact, many more potential problems, but we'd need to see more code.

Comment: One problem I see right away is you're using strlen(buf)... is buf 101 bytes memset to 0? you should always write n, not strlen(buf) because read may have returned less than 100 bytes. also, send n for the same reason.

Comment: Also, a side question; why did you make your code IPv4-specific (by specifying AF_INET and not AF_UNSPEC) and why using the very old routine gethostbyname instead of getaddrinfo?

Comment: @bortzmeyer - I don't think getaddrinfo() is well documented beyond man pages.  I've never seen it in any of the popular "how to do sockets" books.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, don't use `strlen()`.  There's absolutely no guarantee that there'll be a NUL byte anywhere in the file stream, and in fact with a text file there never should be.

Each time around the loop you should output the actual number of bytes that were received, not how many `strlen()` thinks might be in the buffer:

```
do
{
    bytes_received = recv(sock, recv_data, 100, 0);
    if (bytes_received < 0) {
        perror("read");
        break;
    } else if (bytes_received == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        count = write(t, recv_data, bytes_received);
        // in theory - add error check here too!
    }
} while (count > 0);
```

Comment: i have removed strlen and replaced with the actuall recv return but still there is same problem of some(few) unreadable charachter.my second question can we use the same mechanism to send binary file or any other file like songs and videos,or do we need to change the programme to send these kind of file.
Thanks!

Comment: you need to change the other half of the code not to use strlen() either - I only showed one half.  Once it's correct it'll transport any file regardless of type.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your send()s to see if they succeed. You may find that at some point the write buffer (that is, the socket's output buffer) is full and the send fails. This is normal behavior. Send returns the number of bytes sent. If you are not sending multibyte characters, this would probably manifest as missing data rather than corruted data. If you lose one byte of a two byte character, it could result in corruption.

Answer (score -2):

MS Windows systems use carriage return-linefeed as a line ending, linux using just linefeed.

The "unreadable character" is Ctrl-M, the carriage return, character number 13.

Comment: not unless their code says so, it isn't.  stdio does CRLF/CR conversion sometimes, but the read/write system calls don't.

Comment: p.s. he also said this was under UNIX

Comment: You can't know that. According to the OP the environment is UNIX. They didn't say a Windows client to a UNIX server. It could just as easily be buffering issues or other corruption. We can't know until they post something.

Comment: When I answered this, the OP had posted no code. The only thing I had to go on was the OP's statement that "in between the readable charachter there are some unreadable charachter." I was merely trying to eliminate the obvious.

Comment: I think that's generally better done in comments, that way there are no misleading answers for confused newbies :)

Comment: @tpdi - the OP said from the outset that a) he was using system level calls and b) that it was UNIX.  That almost makes your "obvious" CRLF guess impossible.